# Sum of selected rows and adding to the next row in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to sum up all the values in the "S" column for which the "D" values are not zero. Then I would like to sum this result with the value in the next row (marked in red) from the "S" column. In place of the values marked in yellow, I would like to put 0 in new S.

[image]

```
df<-data.frame(product = rep("A",7), data = seq(as.Date("2020-01-06"), as.Date("2020-01-12"), by = "day"),
               D = c(0,200,100,50,0,0,0), S = c(2,20,300,300,200,1,1))

> df
  product       data   D   S
1       A 2020-01-06   0   2
2       A 2020-01-07 200  20
3       A 2020-01-08 100 300
4       A 2020-01-09  50 300
5       A 2020-01-10   0 200
6       A 2020-01-11   0   1
7       A 2020-01-12   0   1
```

Comment: Just making sure this sounds right: you want to create a column `newS` such that, when `D[i]` is 0 and D[i - 1]` is also 0 (or doesn't exist), `newS[i] = S[i]`. When `D[i]` is not 0, `newS[i]` is 0. When `D[i]` is 0 and `D[i - 1]` is not zero, then  `newS[i]` is the sum of `S[i]` and all previous `S` values where `D` is consecutively non-zero. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(idx = cumsum(lag(D == 0, default = TRUE))) %>%
  mutate(`new S` = case_when(
    row_number() == n() ~ sum(S, na.rm = TRUE), 
    TRUE ~ 0)
    ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-idx)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 5
  product data           D     S `new S`
  <fct>   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A       2020-01-06     0     2       2
2 A       2020-01-07   200    20       0
3 A       2020-01-08   100   300       0
4 A       2020-01-09    50   300       0
5 A       2020-01-10     0   200     820
6 A       2020-01-11     0     1       1
7 A       2020-01-12     0     1       1
```